# Оператор false при перегрузки логических операторов

Tags: c#, .net

В какой ситуации вызывается вторая перегрузка, то есть для оператора false?

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var prog = new Programm();
        if(prog)
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }

    public static bool operator true(Programm prog)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator false(Programm prog)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В отличие от оператора `true`, использование оператора `false` выглядит совсем не очевидно.

Согласно спецификации, оператор `&&` вычисляется как `T.false(x) ? x : T.&(x, y)`

Таким образом, он вызовется в выражениях `a && b`.

Однако, чтобы можно было использовать `&&` дополнительно надо определить оператор `&`

Например:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   if (new Program() && new Program()) Console.WriteLine("1"); // NotImplementedException
}
public static bool operator true(Program p) => false;
public static bool operator false(Program p) => throw new NotImplementedException();
public static Program operator &(Program p1, Program p2) => new Program();
```